# Listview getting ambiguous in setcontentview()

Tags: java, android, xml

I want an activity to contain 2 listviews horizontally... I know i did coding correctly but the problem is now whenever it goes to setcontenct view it finds an xml with data like this...........
but  now when i tried to debug my project .It is unable to find the list in setcontentview()

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_compare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="College Compare"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1st College"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/col1_compare"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2nd College"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/col2_compare"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:typeface="serif" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t26"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1st College"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t27"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2nd College"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="#000" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.75"
                    android:text="Estd. In"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/estd_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.12"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/estd_2"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.12"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.75"
                    android:text="Affiliation"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/aff_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.12"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/aff_2"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.12"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.75"
                    android:text="Infrast."
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/infrast_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.12"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/infrast_2"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.12"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.75"
                    android:text="Placemnt"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/placement_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.12"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/placement_2"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.12"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:weightSum="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/cnf"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.12"
                    android:divider="#000"
                    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_2"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.12"
                    android:divider="#000"
                    android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>




 - public class Comparision extends ListActivity{

                @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                comparelist_1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                comparelist_2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                clg1=Comparision1.c1;
                clg2=Comparision1.c2;
                setContentView(R.layout.college_compare);

                TextView tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.col1_compare);
                TextView tv2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.col2_compare);

                tv1.setText(clg1);
                tv2.setText(clg2);

                new getCompare().execute();
            }   

            class getCompare extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                ........
                }




                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {




          // ------------- THis is for the listview---------

           if (jsonString2 != null ) {
                            try{                    


                                JSONObject jsonObject_3= new JSONObject(jsonString2);
                                courses = jsonObject_3.getJSONArray(TAG_JSONARRAY1);

            /*      ---------       Colleges Compare url_2a   --------  */

                                for (int i = 0; i < courses.length() ; i++) {

                                    JSONObject jsonObject = courses.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String course_1=jsonObject.getString("course");

                                    String fee_1=jsonObject.getString("fee");

                    HashMap<String, String> Compare1 = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                                    Compare1.put(C1, course_1);
                                    Compare1.put(C2, fee_1);

                                    comparelist_1.add(Compare1);

                                }
                                //  Collections.sort(suggest);
                            }catch(JSONException e){
                                Log.w("Error", e.getMessage());
                            }

                        }
                        if (jsonString3 != null ) {
                            try{                    


                                JSONObject jsonObject_4= new JSONObject(jsonString3);
                                courses1 = jsonObject_4.getJSONArray(TAG_JSONARRAY1);

         /*         -------------------       Colleges Compare url_2a   --------  */

                                for (int i = 0; i < courses1.length() ; i++) {

                                    JSONObject jsonObject = courses1.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String course_2=jsonObject.getString("course");

                                    String fee_2=jsonObject.getString("fee");

                        HashMap<String, String> Compare2 = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                                    Compare2.put(C3, course_2);
                                    Compare2.put(C4, fee_2);

                                    comparelist_2.add(Compare2);

                                }
                                //  Collections.sort(suggest);
                            }catch(JSONException e){
                                Log.w("Error", e.getMessage());
                            }

                        }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                ListAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(Comparision.this, comparelist_1,
                            R.layout.course_fee, new String[] { C1,C2 },
                                    new int[] { R.id.coursetv_c_f,R.id.feetv_c_f });
                    setProgressBarVisibility(true);
                    setListAdapter(adapter1);


                ListAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleAdapter(Comparision.this,comparelist_2,
                        R.layout.course_fee, new String[] { C3,C3 },
                                    new int[] { R.id.coursetv_c_f,R.id.feetv_c_f });
                //  setProgressBarVisibility(true);
                    setListAdapter(adapter2);


                }


            }

           }
```

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't have ListViews inside a ScrollView. Secondly, the _one_ ListView meant to be used with a ListActivity should have the id `"@android:id/list"`. Thirdly, the `setListAdapter()` is meant to work with only the ListView with that id, so calling it twice is just going to set it to second Adapter.

Comment: If i want to put it in a scrollvie then??

Comment: Then, how i should manage the SetListAdapter()...  Plz suggest me a solution......

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but ListViews scroll on their own, and having them inside a ScrollView will cause problems.

Comment: ya, i am getting ur point but if someone needs it... then.... I think at times we need such type of things in our project... Its ok if u cant manage this problem but plz suggest me an alternate option ...

Comment: A ListActivity is just a convenience if you want an Activity with only one ListView. If you're going to have two ListViews, you might well use a regular Activity, and access them like you would any other View in your layout. In that case, there are no restrictions on ids.

Comment: If you really, really want a ListView inside a ScrollView, you're welcome to search SO for some options. There are a few I've seen, but they are finicky at best, and often just don't work at all.

Comment: but then how i ll put the data on that list view?? using inflater??

Comment: Or like this        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listPlanet);

  listview.setAdapter(adapter)

Comment: There ya go! The second one. And you'd use `findViewById()` to get the ListViews, just like you did with the TextViews.